# How can I obtain gapless playback with AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayeritem, avqueueplayer

I am trying to play files consecutively with no gap in between. The first thing I tried was using `AVQueuePlayer`:

```
let player = AVQueuePlayer()

let playerItem1 = ...
let playerItem2 = ...

player.insert(playerItem1, after: nil)
player.insert(playerItem2, after: nil)

player.play()
```

This works great and exactly as expected. However, there are some shortcoming of `AVQueuePlayer` and I've decided to instead use `AVPlayer` with a custom queue implementation. The problem I am facing is that although `AVQueuePlayer` is a subclass of `AVPlayer`, I cannot get `AVPlayer` to be gapless. Here's how the code is set up:

```
let playerItem1 = ...
let playerItem2 = ...

let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem1)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

player.play()

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying() {
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nextPlayerItem)
    player.play()
}
```

As you can see, I detect the end of playback of the first item with the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` notification, and then begin playback of the second item. But with this implementation there is a gap between the two items.

How can I change this so that it behaves more like `AVQueuePlayer`, with no gap?

(Please note that I am not interested in using `AVAudioEngine` at this time.)

Comment: What are the shortcomings of `AVQueuePlayer`? Since it extends `AVPlayer`, `AVPlayer` is going to have the same shortcomings I would think.

Comment: You can do with two `AVPlayer` instance. So first initialise one player and start observing progress(50%), if it cross target progress then initialise other player and make sure you call `AVPlayer.prepareToPlay()`. once first player finished then replace that with second player

Comment: @HangarRash I think you have it backwards. Since `AVQueuePlayer` extends `AVPlayer`, it is a more specific type of player. If `AVQueuePlayer` has some shortcomings, we can go back to the more general `AVPlayer` and work from there, creating a new subclass of it that has the desired functionality.

Comment: @SPatel I've actually already tried this too. I had everything loaded, and when the first item is done, immediately start the second player (which was already loaded and prepared). But there is still a gap. Is it possible that `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` isn't called quickly enough? Is there a better way to detect the end?

Comment: try by replacing prepareToPlay with AVPlayer.play() then immediately pause it DispatchQueue.main.async { AVPlayer.pause() }